# Upload Files to Google Drive iFrame using drag & drop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drag-and-drop, google-drive-api

This is a general question. I'm trying to find a solution to upload images on a web page to google drive iFrame on the same web page using drag and drop feature.

[image: Use Case]
Here I have an iFrame Google Sheet on left and a div of images on right. I want to drag and drop images to Google Sheet. It is working when I drag and drop from my computer, but not from div.

Also, in the Sheets iFrame, if I do Insert > Image, the modal for insert image is showing blank, its not asking me to upload an image or provide url.

Are these limitations of an iFrame or is there any way to overcome it.

I have knowledge in JavaScript (Angular, Node) and PHP.

Any help is appreciated. I don't need code, just an idea of implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading files to Google Drive, follow the [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) using either simple, multipart or resumable uploads. There's no mention of drag and drop shortcuts so far. So stick with whats in the documentation or implement your own.